# Compactness of a special kind of Integral operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, compactness, integral-operators

Let $(S(t))_{t>0}$ be a continuous operator from $L^2(0,1)$ to its self and Let $K$ be the operator $$\eqalign{
  & K:{L^2}(0,1) \to {L^2}(0,1)  \cr 
  & f: \to (Kf)(x) = \int\limits_0^1 {k(s,x)S(s)f(s)ds}  \cr} $$
where $$k \in {L^2}(0,1) \times {L^2}(0,1)$$
It is well known that if $S=I$ then $K$ is compact operator.
What can I say about the compactness of $K$ is this case?
Thank you.

Comment: I see no reason for $K$ even to be well-defined in general, forget about boundedness or compactness. You need to assume something else to make this construction meaningful (I interpret $S(s)f(s)$ as $(S(s)f)(s)$)

Comment: I think you also need to be explicit as to exactly in what sense $S(t)$ is "continuous".  Continuous for each $t$?  A continuous curve in the space of (continuous?) operators (with what topology?)

Comment: In fact, $S(t)$ is C0_semogroup of operators on $L^2$ so it is continuous wth respect to its topology.

Answer (score 1):

Your question must be reformulated to take into account the comments. Let us just say here that Hilbert-Schmidt operators (operators whose kernels are in $L^2((0,1)^2)$) make an ideal of the bounded operators so that composing a HS operator with a bounded operator gives a HS operator.